# C# Class Library - How to Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio Express.

I am writing an Class Library and want to debug it, but I don´t get how I do that. 
The dll is for an App which itself injects into an other Software. I have direct Access to that App.

So far I have attached the Debugger to the App, but what now? Do I have now to specify something so that always when I debug it a new Version is builded in the Plugin Directory of the App? Or shall I set my Working Dir to the Apps Plugin Directory?

I have read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291243%28v=vs.71%29.aspx and various other resources, but it never happens what is expected.

Comment: Is it unit testable?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new project to your solution that outputs an executable assembly, such as WinForms, Console, or Web.

Set this new project to be the startup project.

Add the Class Library project to the Executable projects references.

Write your test code.

Run the executable project.

Comment: And how shall I do that if my dll get its Values from the App?

Comment: If by 'App' you mean your existing plugin host... then you would need to fake those values from your test harness app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be confused what debugging in visual studio. Debugging in Visual Studio allows you to set breakpoints and see errors more clearly by highlighting the line of code that is throwing the error.

> I am writing an Class Library and want to debug it, but I don´t get how I do that. The dll is for an App which itself injects into an other Software. I have direct Access to that App.

Library classes are hard to debug, b/c they won't want to run by themselves. I actually wouldn't call your class a library. Your code is an application that "hooks" itself into another software. You can debug your application by running it with a debugger attached (simply pressing start should attach the debugger unless you explicitly ask for it not to be attached in project settings) and then using your application to inject itself into another software. **Any errors that result from the application while in testing will be caught by the debugger.**

Comment: I knew what debugging is. I am just not used to Projects where I have the need of another Software to let them Run. It seems that I misspelled it. The App is hooking into another Software. My dll itself is called by that App and also gets it values from there. That´s why I attached Visual Studio to the App. But don´t get how to debug my dll now.